# View in RStudio a table with crossed data of two labelled of a tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, view, rstudio, tibble

If I have a data frame (or a tibble) `df` as the following:

```
x <- c(2,2,2,1,1,2,3)
y <- c(5,5,4,5,4,4,5)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Then, if I cross data with the instruction `table(df$x,df$y)` I get a matrix form:

```
     4    5
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    0    1
```

But if I do a `View` of the same instruction what I see has a different structure, such as you can see next:

```
 1    4    1
 2    4    2
 3    4    0
 1    5    1
 2    5    2
 3    5    1
```

Do you know if there is some instruction to make something similar to `View` (taking into account its description: `Invoke a spreadsheet-style data viewer on a matrix-like R object`) preserving the first structure for the intersection table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the issue is that a table is not close enough to a matrix-like R object.  If I look at str(table(df$x,df$y)), I see that it is a list

Comment: In fact it has dimensions. I am asking for a way to get the same result that View, but for an object like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `table(...)` is an object of class `"table"`.  There's an `as.data.frame.table` method that rearranges the data; presumably `View()` is using that.  This makes sense, because tables can have other than 2 indices; e.g. `table(df$x, df$y, df$x)` will have 3 indices, so it needs to be reshaped to become a dataframe.

If you know your table has two indices, you could use `unclass()`before passing it to `View()`, i.e.  `View(unclass(table(df$x, df$y)))`.